# how to dynamically remove/add options from/to dropdown using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-filter

On my Angular template there is a set of cascade dropdowns (Country, State, City), an Add button, and a table with Delete button on each row.  All the data in the dropdowns is retrieved from asp.net webapi unfiltered at load time. I am trying to do the flowing with filter:

1. When all the dropdown values are selected, clicking the add button the value will be added to a table below it. The value is hidden (not deleted) from the dropdown.
2. When clicking the Delete button in the respective table row, it will delete (not hidden) the row.  If the deleted City is still in the dropdown, it will be un-hidden.
3. At the load time, the City dropdown also need to filter out value already in the table.
4. Each button click will Ajax post to the webapi to update the server database

The table data is an array of objects with 7 fields (id, countryId, country, stateId, state, cityId, city) like below.

```js
[{
  id: 1,
  level1id: 101,
  level1: 'USA',
  level2id: 39,
  level2: 'California',
  level3id: 4210,
  level3: 'San Diego'
}, {
  id: 19,
  level1id: 101,
  level1: 'USA',
  level2id: 33,
  level2: 'Oregon',
  level3id: 5905,
  level3: 'Portland'
}, {
  id: 1,
  level1id: 101,
  level1: 'USA',
  level2id: 690,
  level2: 'Washington',
  level3id: 1223,
  level3: 'Seattle'
}]
```

After applying the filter Seattle, Portland, and San Diego will be removed from the dropdown.

```js
[{
  id: 3521,
  city: 'San Francisco'
}, {
  id: 5234,
  city: 'Los Angeles'
}, {
  id: 9792,
  city: 'New York'
}, {
  id: 8899,
  city: 'Chicago'
}]
```

Comment: Post your full working code to better results.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom filter that will receive the original cities array (the one that goes into the drop-downs) and the list of selected cities (the one that goes into the table) and filter the selected cities out of the list of all the cities.

Based on your objects, and assuming `level3id` is the one you want to filter, you can go with this one:

```
  // This is the custom filter - add it to your model 
  app.filter('selectedCities', function() {

    /**
     * This will be the returned filter function
     * input is the list of cities that needs to be filtered
     * selected is the list of items in the table
     */
    return function(input, selected) {

      var selected_cities = {}
      var output = [];

      //first we create hash map with all the selected cities
      //This will enable us to locate a selected city in ~O(1)
      angular.forEach(selected, function(selected_city) {

        selected_cities[selected_city.level3id] = true;

      })

      /**
       * now we go through the cities.
       * we check if the city is in the hash of selected cities
       * if its not there - we add it to the output 
       */
      angular.forEach(input, function(city) {

          if (!(city.id in selected_cities)) {
            output.push(city)
          }
      })

      return output;
    }

  });
```

In the drop down you probably have some loop like `ng-repeat = "city in cities"`, and lets say the table data object name is `table_selected_data` so you can use the filter like this:

```
ng-repeat = "city in cities | selectedCities:table_selected_data"
```